# Specializing general CRT formula to constant residue case

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

The Chinese Remainder Theorem states that if $n_1, n_2$ are coprime, and

$x = a_1 \pmod{n_1}$

$x = a_2 \pmod{n_2}$

then in the space of $\pmod{n_1n_2}$ there exists a unique $x$ given by

$x = a_1 n_2 (n_2^{-1} \pmod{n_1}) + a_2 n_1 (n_1^{-1} \pmod{n_2}) \pmod{n_1n_2}$.

---

In the proof of correctness for [RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/rsa-proof-of-correctness?noredirect=1&lq=1), a special case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem is used where

$x = r \pmod{n_1}$

$x = r \pmod{n_2}$

and thus,

$x = r \pmod{n_1n_2}$.

---

How is

$x = r n_2 (n_2^{-1} \pmod{n_1}) + r n_1 (n_1^{-1} \pmod{n_2}) \pmod{n_1n_2}$

equivalent to

$x = r \pmod{n_1n_2}$?

I am not sure how to prove the general case of this without being given values of $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Comment: The case $r=1$ is sufficient.  Once you have that, you can simply multiply by general $r$ modulo $n_1 n_2$.

Comment: You need $(n_1,n_2)= 1$  for this to be true.

Comment: $\gcd(n_1, n_2) = 1$ is true since $n_1$ and $n_2$ are coprime if that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full proof, but might provide some intuition: One way I like to think about CRT is that "if $\gcd(n_1,n_2) = 1$, then for any $a_1,a_2$, there is a unique $y \in \mathbb{Z}/n_1n_2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y \equiv a_1 \pmod {n_1}$ and $y \equiv a_2 \pmod {n_2}$."

In this case, for $a_1 = a_2 = r$, we have $r \equiv r \pmod {n_1}$ and $r \equiv r \pmod {n_2}$, so we are done.

Comment: But how does one go from $r \equiv r \pmod{n_1}$ and $r \equiv r \pmod{n_2}$ to $r \equiv r \pmod{n_1n_2}$ ?

Comment: CRT guarantees that this value is unique; since $r$ works, it must be the value.

Comment: Ah, ok that would make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because the inverses modulo $n_i$ are obtained through a *Bézout's identity*:
$$un_1+vn_2=1,$$
so that $x\equiv run_1+rvn_2=r\cdot 1\mod n_1n_2$.

Comment: Walk me through this. So by definition of co-prime, $gdc(n_1, n_2) = 1$. Bezout's identity states that $u$ and $v$ exist such that $u n_1 + v n_2 = 1$. $u$ and $v$ can be found through extended Euclid's algorithm. And you're saying $u = n_1^{-1} \pmod{n_2}$ and $v = n_2^{-1} \pmod{n_1}$.

Comment: Yes.  And $n_1^{-1}\bmod n_2\equiv u$, $n_2^{-1}\bmod n_1\equiv v$

Comment: Wait how were those general identities for $u$ and $v$ constructed?

Comment: Do you mean the last ones?

Comment: Yes, because extended Euclid works for specified values right?

Comment: Extended Euclid yields values for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I understand that part but how did you get $n_1^{-1}\bmod n_2\equiv u$ and $n_2^{-1}\bmod n_1\equiv v$ without knowing what $n_1$ and $n_2$ are?

Comment: Read Bézout's relation  mod. $n_2$ and mod. $n_1$: it becomes$$un_1\equiv 1\mod n_2, \qquad vn_2\equiv 1\mod n_1.$$